# gitlab ci cache/keep golang packages between stages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I use gitlab-ci to test, compile and deploy a small golang application but the problem is that the stages take longer than necessary because they have to fetch all of the dependencies every time.

How can I keep the golang dependencies between two stages (test and build)?

This is part of my current gitlab-ci config:

```
test:
    stage: test
    script:
        # get dependencies
        - go get github.com/foobar/...
        - go get github.com/foobar2/...
        # ...
        - go tool vet -composites=false -shadow=true *.go
        - go test -race $(go list ./... | grep -v /vendor/)

compile:
    stage: build
    script:
        # getting the same dependencies again
        - go get github.com/foobar/...
        - go get github.com/foobar2/...
        # ...
        - go build -race -ldflags "-extldflags '-static'" -o foobar
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - foobar
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As mentioned by [Yan Foto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2295964/yan-foto), [you can only use paths that are within the project workspace.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache) But you can move the `$GOPATH` to be inside your project, as suggested by [extrawurst blog](https://blog.extrawurst.org/general/2018/12/05/go-and-gitlab-ci.html#regarding-gitlab-ci-caching).

```yaml
test:
  image: golang:1.11
  cache:
    paths:
      - .cache
  script:
    - mkdir -p .cache
    - export GOPATH="$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.cache"
    - make test
```

Comment: Thanks! Both your and Yan Foto's answer are useful workarounds, I upvoted both. What you're suggesting here seems a bit less hacky so I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 7):

This is a pretty tricky task, as [GitLab does not allow caching outside the project directory](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#cache). A quick and dirty task would be to copy the contents of `$GOPATH` under some directory inside the project (say `_GO`), cache it and copy it upon each stage start back to `$GOPATH`:

```yaml
after_script:
  - cp -R $GOPATH ./_GO || :

before_script:
  - cp -R _GO $GOPATH

cache:
  untracked: true
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME"
  paths:
    - _GO/
```

---

**WARNING**: This is just a (rather ugly) workaround and I haven't tested it myself. It should only exhibit a possible solution.